# I would like to know if patent EP2152282A1 is still a valid patent?

Tags: validity

In reference to the patent: [EP2152282A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP2152282A1)

Answer (score 1):

According to European Patent Register Said Patent application is deemed to be withdrawn in 2011.

[image]